# Is it possible to have an ArrayList of size -1?

Tags: java, arraylist

Is it possible to have an ArrayList of size -1? Or atleast some flag set to a number less than 0/Invalid that I can used to detect a condition?

Comment: No, the size of an ArrayList is always non-negative.

Comment: Why? It's not a final class, so you could create a subclass that returns a size of -1 if a condition holds.

Comment: Override the `size()` method.

Comment: I'm going to be Judgy McJudgerson here, and say that while you technically CAN do this, it's not in the spirit of the Collections framework and it has a definite code smell. Detect your condition with a `null` or empty ArrayList if you must.

Comment: You can do it, but you should **NOT** do it. There are too many potential places where someone might receive a `List`, relying on the **contract** that is set up with this interface, and do something like `if (list.size() != 0) list.get(0);` (even though `if (!list.isEmpty()) list.get(0);` would be the preferred way to do this).

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of answering the question asked, the size of the provided `ArrayList` class is non-negative, however, as some of the comments have suggested, you can override the `size()` method in the `ArrayList` class, and have it return what you want.

```
public class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    @Override
    public int size() {
        if (somecondition) {
            return -1;
        }
        return super.size();
    }
}
```

It should be noted however, that there are serious implications with overriding methods of the classes implementing the `List` interface, where certain users of those classes will be expecting sound implementations of these methods, and adding additional functionality *could* break that contract. It's probably a better idea to detect your condition external to `ArrayList` and use that, as it's likely there are better ways to accomplish what you describe.

Comment: "*you can override the size() method in the `ArrayList`*" Yeah, but it is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: @Lii yes, but the OP asked for a way to do it, and this is _a way_ to do it. I'll update it with the disclaimer.